# Is there any image filters library like prisma ? for react native

Tags: react-native

Is there any image filters library like prisma ? for react native

i am seeking for image filters folks,

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at gl-react implementation for react-native?
I didn't try it in any project yet, but looks promising.

https://github.com/gre/gl-react/tree/master/packages/gl-react-native